# What's the shortest way to calculate the position of item in flat 2D list by coordinates?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, list, math

**I'm looking for the shortest equation to find the flattened position of an ordered pair.**

Let's use a TicTacToe board for example.

```
|---|---|---|
| 0 | 1 | 2 |
|---|---|---|
| 3 | 4 | 5 |
|---|---|---|
| 6 | 7 | 8 |
|---|---|---|
```

Given `(1, 1)`, how can I get `4`?
What about `(2, 1)` to get `5`?

I would like the solution to be general and not language syntax-specific.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "algorithm"? Isn't it just indexing on an array?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ More or less wanted an algebraic equation.

Comment: Given (x, y), `c * x + y` where c is the number of columns assuming row-major ordering.

Comment: Google "row major indexing".

Answer (score 1):

Since you're numbering along rows first, the formula you need is `row_number * column_count + column_number`.

If you were numbering down columns first, or right-to-left, or any other variation, you would have to adjust that formula accordingly.

Keep in mind, also, that this works for zero-based indexing only.

Comment: This seems like it was super simple for you guys. I probably need sleep.

Comment: I've spent longer than I should have figuring out this exact thing in the past.